# multiple content in article model (blog)

Tags: django, django-models

I am designing a blog as my personal proj but having seen many blogs online I have noticed one trend, some of them are diverse with content put any type of content, (what I mean to say is) article will have heading then some description then some code snippet than some picture then again some code snippet, then maybe some video clip, now my query am I supposed to design my model such that it should have all that variety as fields inside my models? that's what I am confused about

```
class Entry(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User,
                             on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    topic = models.ForeignKey(Topic, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    text = models.TextField()
    date_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    picture = models.ImageField(upload_to='images', blank=True)
    video = models.FileField(upload_to='videos', blank=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'entries'

    @property
    def get_photo_url(self):
        if self.picture and hasattr(self.picture, 'url'):
            return self.picture.url
        else:
            return " "

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.text[:80]}...'
```

> should i add fields like ( code , and other type of stuff )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Ckeditor](https://django-ckeditor.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).

Using it you will be able to write text, image, code, video all in one field.

You can see this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=L6y6cn1XUfw).